# Generating AC current from microcontroller

Tags: current-transformer

I have a CT that has a 1000 turns secondary winding, 1000 turns test winding. So the ratio between secondary and test winding is 1:1, and from primary to secondary is 1000:1. The test winding is not always active, compared to the secondary winding which has a burden resistor and is being continuously monitored with an ADC. What I'm trying to do is generate a detectable 50Hz AC current (something between 30 uA to 10 mA) with the microcontroller to perform the test function.

The CT detects current as low as 10 mA in the primary. Let's say we have 20 mA in the primary, we have 20 uA in the secondary. So that's why even 20 uA would be enough as the test signal (I may be wrong).

So I came up with the circuit attached below. The idea is to generate a PWM and make it pass through a low pass filter to get a sine wave. Added the capacitor at the output of the opamp for ac coupling and a resistor to limit the current.

Would this approach work? Any better suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You could just use two mosfets to make the output go rail to rail, instead of having an opamp. It depends exactly what sort of output you need. Do you actually care a lot about the specific voltage output?

Comment: Do you mean like a push-pull after the low pass filter? Also, I don't have dual power supply. Do you have a reference schematic?

Comment: Yes. You dont need a dual power supply, you would just power it the same way that you're powering your opamp. How big is R2? Also, how much like a sine wave does this have to be? Do you just want an alternating current, or do you need something close to a sine wave?

Comment: I haven't calculated neither R2 nor C2. I'm needing some help on that. I just have the concept circuit.

Comment: what is the burden resistance? what is the DC resistanc of your primary? and secondary.

Comment: @BeB00 I just want an alternating current, not need to look exactly like a sine wave. Does the micro push pull type output work instead of adding external transistors?

Comment: _"I have a CT that has a 1000 turns secondary winding, 1000 turns test winding."_ - where did you get this transformer from? Can you supply specifications? What are the secondary and test winding DC resistances? What is the exact purpose of your 'test function'?

Comment: You really don't need a dual-supply. You need an H-Bridge feeding your winding; solved problem.

Comment: @BruceAbbott This transformer is from a ground fault device. Secondary and test windings DC resistances are 76 ohms. The test function is just to "test" the device is working properly by injecting a intentional ground fault current in the test winding.

Answer (score 1):

you're driving the primary resistance secondary resistance and the burden resistor all effectively in series. (the 1:1 ratio greatly simplifies the impedance transform) so your driver needs to produce sufficient voltage on the primary terminals to drive the needed current through that resistance.

An audio amplifier chip might be suitable where you draw the op-amp.

you're going to need to isolate the primary when you want to measure real-world currents. so you may need a relay in the circuit too.